# Cache behavior in dd command

Tags: memory, dd, io, cache

I am performing some `dd` outputs and running in parallel `vmstat`:

With no direct write (i.e. via cache)

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=somefile.txt bs=1M count=200 
200+0 records in
200+0 records out
209715200 bytes (210 MB, 200 MiB) copied, 1,31332 s, 160 MB/s



$ vmstat 1 1000
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0     64 2659604 383244 3596884    0    0     3    47   34   14 27  7 66  0  0
 1  0     64 2509432 383244 3746080    0    0     0     0 1005 2278  5 20 75  0  0
 0  0     64 2452560 383248 3807932    0    0     4 204880 1175 2321  4 12 75  9  0
 0  0     64 2453144 383248 3807548    0    0     0     0  814 2677  5  2 93  0  0
 1  0     64 2444868 383248 3814516    0    0     0   244  529 1746  4  2 94  0  0
 0  0     64 2445756 383248 3814516    0    0     0     0  495 1957  3  1 96  0  0
```

I see that it performed more or less one bulk write

With direct write

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=somefile.txt bs=1M count=200 oflag=direct
200+0 records in
200+0 records out
209715200 bytes (210 MB, 200 MiB) copied, 1,6902 s, 124 MB/s



$ vmstat 1 1000
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0     64 2623556 383248 3603572    0    0     3    47   35   14 27  7 66  0  0
 1  0     64 2613784 383248 3611220    0    0     0 88064 1001 2573  5 15 79  1  0
 0  0     64 2612236 383256 3611804    0    0     8 116736  912 2033  1 18 78  3  0
 4  0     64 2621076 383256 3604232    0    0     0    96 1086 3250  8  3 89  0  0
```

My question is the following:

How does this fragmentation of direct writing operation occurs?
What is the (kernel?) parameter that determined the file should be broken (when not passing via cache) into 2 chunks of 88 and 116 MB (and not say into 4 chunks of 50MB)?

Would the results be different if i had used the `oflag=sync` instead of `direct`?

Comment: You are using `vmstat` to get the stats output once every second (for 1000 seconds), why do you give significance to the fact that in one run of `dd`, all data was written more or less during one such interval while in the other run, the interval ended partway through the operation?

Comment: because after multiple experiments this behavior seems consistent; after repeating it with 1G output,using the `direct` flag seems to break it into more or less 10 writes of 100MB each while not using it caused 3-4 writes (albeit uneven in size); what is more, not using the `direct` flag causes the writes to be done immediately (in terms of the `bo` appearing right away in the `vmstat` output)

Comment: If you are really interested in why the kernel does things this way, I'd (1) read kernel code, (2) use kernel tracing, e.g. `perf` or or `ftrace`. I wouldn't expect the high-level behaviour you observe to have a simple explanation or a single parameter (but I don't know).